# UserManager.GetRolesAsync() method

Tags: c#, asp.net, identity, roles

i want to add user role to claims

```
var claims = new[]
            {
                new Claim("Email", model.Email),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, _userManger.GetRolesAsync(user).ToString())
                
            };
```

but this method doesn`t work.  how  can I get role name as string?

Comment: Maybe clarify what "doesn't work" means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this might work for you,

```
var roles = await _userMgr.GetRolesAsync(user);
var claims = new List<Claim>();

claims.Add(new Claim("Email", model.Email));
claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id));
foreach (var role in roles)
{
   claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
}
```

GetRolesAsync(user) returns a List of role names (strings) there may be more than 1.

Comment: Thank you. Solution is very easy but i can`t got it (;